# Rails 3 plugin - how to access app's model file in require statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am writing a plugin in Rails 3.2.6 - my plugin is supposed to modify my User model (located in app/models/user.rb) - however, I cannot find the proper way to reference that file from the plugin in a require statement.

I tried `require 'user'`, `require 'app/models/user'`, and a bunch of stuff trying to use Rails.root and other variables - nothing works and I get an error "Uninitialized constant User" when trying to run the app.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? BTW, this plugin was build as a gem and is included in my Gemfile (which pulls it from github).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on ruby 1.9, you should be able to use require_relative

```
#assuming /lib/yourfile.rb
require_relative '../app/models/user.rb'
```

If you are on an older ruby, you might try

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '../app/models/user.rb'
```

Comment: Didn't work in my case, but I think I have other issues with the plugin. Tried this with a quick test case and it works fine, so I am voting this the answer. Thanks!